# Multiple threading php script

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, cron, pthreads

I have a cron which is running a php script.
As it is, it is taking several or even more than 10 hours to run.
It is taking this long because in the script it is fetching and processing many several website pages after each other and each page must wait for the previous page to finish loading/processing before it starts.
My question is, is there any way, to load and process many several website pages at once so as to save on time?

Right now I have something which looks like

```
<?php

//loop for each url link
$my_var = file_get_contents($urlLink);
//do some processing on $my_var

?>
```

Comment: You can look at [`curl_multi_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) but don't be confused about what it does - it's ansync, not threaded. Where is your actual bottle neck fetching the URIs?

Comment: Fetching the URIs, yes.

Comment: Personally can't recommend going the `pthreads` route. Would either break list into 10 parts and run 10 of that script, or, rearchitect so it works more like a queue, use some `curl_multi` to fetch and add the jobs to the queue, separate out the code that processes those jobs. You can then better find a balance.

Comment: ^ guess the negative is then you are needing to persist the data. Maybe there is already disk I/O. Dunno with the little code provided. Might be something I would not do purely in PHP.

Comment: Ye. I might do it like a queue. Now I must go and find a good example of where someone has added curl results to a stack/queue and take it from there.

Comment: There are some serious tools out there for pulling in URIs like that. Can get a serious firehose going. Spacing on names now... Can only think of [turbolift](https://github.com/cloudnull/turbolift), which actually is probably worth taking a look at, though more for working with CDNs. Breaking it up gives you more options as far as using the right tool for the specific job.